# define SOMETHING ('w' << 8)

Tags: c, bitmask

I came accros this line of code:

```
#define BWAKUP              ('w' << 8)
```

What does it do? Its the same as:

```
#define BWAKUP              (167000)
```

In addition, another definition as :

```
#define CWAKUP                  (1 + BWAKUP)
```

is equivalent to :

```
#define CWAKUP                  (356000)
```

Right ?

Comment: No the same as `#define BWAKUP  (0167<<8)`, 167 is the octal code for ASCII `'w'`.

Comment: Is `119*256=30464`. BTW depends on platform.

Comment: That depends on the character encoding of the target architecture. `'w'` is not `119` in all cases. *Why* it's there depends entirely on the context of the code, and there's not enough information in the question to know why `'w'` is used here.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Can't be. That would be `0167` left shifted by 9 places, but we only shift by eight places.

Comment: How do you know it's the same as 167000?

Comment: Basically, because I didn't understand and made mistakes during conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line define a macro `BWAKUP` which expands to the expression `('w' << 8)`. That expression has, assuming your platform uses ASCII, the value 119 · 256 = 30464 which is not equal to `167000`.Similarly, `CWAKUP` expands to `(1 + ('w' << 8))` with the numeric value 30465, again assuming your system uses ASCII.

Without more context I can't tell you what the meaning of these macros is.

Comment: Ok then, `#define DWKUP (8 + BWAKUP)` equivalent to `#define DWKUP (8 + ('w' << 8)` would be equal to 30208 right ?

Comment: @SnP No. that's 30472. If you mean octal, than please say so. In C, octal numbers begin with a 0 to distinguish them from decimal numbers.

Comment: Ok, It was tough but I understand now ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

> I came accros this line of code:
>
> ```
> #define BWAKUP              ('w' << 8)
> ```
>
> What does it do?

It defines the preprocessor macro `BWAKUP` as `('w' << 8)`. That means that whenever `BWAKUP` appears in the source code, it will be replaced with `('w' << 8)`. For example, `printf("%i\n", BWAKUP);` will be changed to `printf("%i\n", ('w' << 8));`.

> Its the same as:
>
> ```
> #define BWAKUP              (167000)
> ```

No, it's not.

> In addition, another definition as :
>
> ```
> #define CWAKUP                  (1 + BWAKUP)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to :
>
> ```
> #define CWAKUP                  (356000)
> ```
>
> Right ?

No, but it would be equivalent to `#define CWAKUP (1 + ('w' << 8))`.